# Bing Maps API map center offset

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, bing-maps

I using Bing Maps API to show a location on my map and when I put an infobox on it, the infobox is positioned out of the frame. Is it possible to offset the map lets say by 50 pixels down so my infobox isn't getting cut off? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

it is, but to be honest you are better off centering the map then opening the popup, not as nice but less problems fitting on the map

Comment: how do I offset the map? I do not want to modify the coordinates in my database so without change them, how do I offset something? Thanks. Also why would centering the map and then placing the popup be better. BTW When I said out of the frame, I meant the bottom portion is visible but the top is getting cut off.

Comment: sorry perhaps I misunderstood, are you saying your popup is so large that even with the pin centred its getting displayed off the map either vertically or horizontally.

Comment: as thats what you want to do look at the two methods called tryLocationToPixel and tryPixelToLocation on the main map object:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427609.aspx

These will let you take your map's center lat/lon, convert it to pixels on the map, offset it by the number of pixels you desire and convert that back into a lat/lon to then move the map to that location before opening the popup

Comment: English? Just kidding, thanks! I have been trying to find this but I couldn't find it online anywhere.